# RSpec: use `receive ... exactly ... with ... and_return ...` with different `with` arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

I'm writing an expectation which checks whether a method is called two times with different arguments and returns different values. At the moment I'm just writing the expectation twice:

```rb
expect(ctx[:helpers]).to receive(:sanitize_strip).with(
  %{String\n<a href="http://localhost:3000/">description</a> <br/>and newline\n<br>},
  length: nil
).and_return('String description and newline')

expect(ctx[:helpers]).to receive(:sanitize_strip).with(
  %{String\n<a href="http://localhost:3000/">description</a> <br/>and newline\n<br>},
  length: 15
).and_return('String descr...')
```

I wonder if I can use `receive ... exactly ... with ... and_return ...` instead; something like:

```rb
expect(ctx[:helpers]).to receive(:sanitize_strip).exactly(2).times.with(
  %{String\n<a href="http://localhost:3000/">description</a> <br/>and newline\n<br>},
  length: nil
).with(
  %{String\n<a href="http://localhost:3000/">description</a> <br/>and newline\n<br>},
  length: 15
).and_return('String descr...', 'String description and newline')
```

The code above doesn't work, it raises the following error:

```
1) Types::Collection fields succeeds
   Failure/Error: context[:helpers].sanitize_strip(text, length: truncate_at)

     #<Double :helpers> received :sanitize_strip with unexpected arguments
       expected: ("String\n<a href=\"http://localhost:3000/\">description</a> <br/>and newline\n<br>", {:length=>15})
            got: ("String\n<a href=\"http://localhost:3000/\">description</a> <br/>and newline\n<br>", {:length=>nil})
     Diff:
     @@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
      ["String\n<a href=\"http://localhost:3000/\">description</a> <br/>and newline\n<br>",
     - {:length=>15}]
     + {:length=>nil}]
```

Is there a way to use `receive ... exactly ... with ... and_return ...` with different `with` arguments?

Comment: Maybe `hash_including({})` instead of `length: nil`? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [`rspec-any_of` gem](https://github.com/toptal/rspec-any_of) that allows for the following syntax by prodiding `all_of` argument matcher:

```
expect(ctx[:helpers]).to receive(:sanitize_strip).with(
  %{String\n<a href="http://localhost:3000/">description</a> <br/>and newline\n<br>}
  all_of({length: 15}, {length: nil})
)
.and_return('String descr...', 'String description and newline')
.twice
```

Comment: Amazing! And thank you and your colleagues for the gem!

Answer (score 1):

Without using an extra gem, you could call the normal `expect ... to receive ... with ... and_return ...` with variables from inside an `each` block:

```
describe '#sanitize_strip' do
  let(:html) do
    %{String\n<a href="http://localhost:3000/">description</a> <br/>and newline\n<br>}
  end
  let(:test_data) do
    [
      [[html, length: nil], 'String description and newline'],
      [[html, length: 15], 'String descr...']
    ]
  end

  it 'returns sanitized strings stripped to the number of characters provided' do
    test_data.each do |args, result|
      expect(ctx[:helpers]).to receive(:sanitize_strip).with(*args).and_return(result)
    end

    # Trigger the calls to sanitize_strip
  end
end
```